# Iterating through Evaluate Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list with duplicates in `A2:A4` :

```
SYSTEM1
SYSTEM1
SYSTEM2
```

I wanted to print out from `Application.Evaluate("UNIQUE(A2:A4)")`:

```
SYSTEM1
SYSTEM2
```

I tried this but it seems like it didn't print anything :,(

```
Dim UniqueVal
 For Each UniqueVal In Application.Evaluate("UNIQUE(A2:A4)")
 Debug.Print UniqueVal
 Next
```

Comment: In what version of Excel do you try it? Do you try it in Excel 365?

Comment: Yes, mine was Excel for Microsoft 365

Comment: Was? If it **is**, the above code should work. `Evaluate` only evaluates an existing worksheet function result... Of course, the data to be evaluated to be in the active sheet.

Comment: I just realized I forgot something to add. I'm such an idiot. Thx btw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code to work, the Immediate Window must be open and the worksheet containing the data must be active:

```
Sub whatever()
    Dim u
    For Each u In Application.Evaluate("UNIQUE(A2:A4)")
        Debug.Print u
    Next u
End Sub
```

[image]

Where the active worksheet is like:

[image]

Comment: that's exactly what I needed. Thanks :)